# flow deployment error about api version

Tags: api, salesforcedx, deployment, visual-workflow, visualstudiocode

after launching this command from the visual studio code terminal :

```
 sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath .\force-app\main\default\ --apiversion 47.0
```

I receive the following errors:

```
force-app\main\default\flows\Chargent.flow-meta.xml                                                Property 'start' not valid in version 46.0
force-app\main\default\flows\Automated_Access.flow-meta.xml                                        Property 'start' not valid in version 46.0
force-app\main\default\flows\Automated_Removal.flow-meta.xml                                       Property 'start' not valid in version 46.0
```

how can I fix?

EDIT: I deployed succesfully by changing the attribute "apiVersion" of the file sfdx-config.json to "47.0". For some reason the param --apiversion on the command line didn't work as expected

Comment: Did you make any changes to those flows? What is the specific error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously your deployment command doesn't take your "--apiversion 47.0" for real. Try increasing your API version in the project file. Or try clearing the .sfdx folder in order to delete any cached stuff, that way it might recognize your requested change in the API version.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Hyperzwerg 's answer:

1. Existing entry in **sfdx-project.json**:

   "sourceApiVersion": "47.0"
2. Retrieved flow using :
   sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Flow:{flowName}" -u {targetUserName}
3. Attempted deploy using:
   sfdx force:source:deploy -m "Flow:{flowName}"
4. Encountered errors:

   Property 'runInMode' not valid in version 47.0

   Property 'storeOutputAutomatically' not valid in version 47.0 (153:20)
5. Modified **sfdx-project.json**:

   "sourceApiVersion": "49.0"
6. Attempted deploy again (same as step#3)

Deploy worked, no errors encountered.